# How do I preselect in a drop down list box?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to preselect like this:

```
<option selected="yes" value="test1" >test1</option
```

But I get a message in VS2010 saying "Validation HTML5: The value permitted for this attribute do not include 'yes'.

Am I doing something wrong. I thought the way to preselect was as above.

Answer (score 4):

it should be selected="selected"

```
<option selected="selected" value="test1" >test1</option>
```

Answer (score 3):

Selected attribute only contain selected value, like this:

```
<option selected="selected" value="test1">test1</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<option selected="selected">test1</option>
```

Would be the correct way to do it, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

try `selected="selected"` or you can just leave the selected without any value like `<option selected>test1</option>`